# How to set 3 dot menu image as showcase view target?

Tags: android, android-layout

> I need to get the id of the 3 dot menu on action bar.I need it to use
>   showcaseview on it to show a tutorial to the user.
>
> If it is not possible,then is there any way to set showcaseView target
>   as 3dot menu image?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Activity is AppCompatActivity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
if (toolbar != null) {
        // 0 - title
        // 1 - options menu
        View menuLayout = toolbar.getChildAt(1);
        if (menuLayout instanceof ViewGroup) {
            // index here depends on actual toolbar layout
            View menu3dots = ((ViewGroup)menuLayout).getChildAt(0);
        }
}
```

Comment: worked with me .. but in my case, I had to use toolbar.GetChildAt(2) since the first element was the activity toolbar back button.

Answer (score 0):

it has no id; you must inflate the view to create the three dots. You also need another xml file defining the menu.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The xml file:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".My_Activity">
    <item android:id="@+id/more_info" android:title="@string/moreInfo"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: i already code the menu,but my question is how to set it as a showcase view target?